# The microsoft jet database cannot open the file '...' It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view its data

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have a WinForms application that I have taken over support for and it was build using Visual Studio 2005 with VB.Net. The application makes use of an Access database. It runs fine when it is installed as a standalone application, but the install cd for the application also allows for a network install and this is where I am currently encountering issues.

To test the network install I created a folder on my server (Windows Server 2003 SP2) and copied the Access database to this folder. I created a share for this folder and gave everyone full permissions to the share. Then on the workstation I installed the application and gave the path to the database as follows:

\\myserver\myshare\mydb.mdb

(The install steps here are as per the instructions given on the installation cd)

The workstation that I installed it on is Windows 7 Ultimate. When I run the application, I get the error message given in the title when the application tries to read the database file. I have confirmed that I am able to write to the shared folder on the server, so I don't think this is a permissions issue. Also, the database file is not in use at all, so it is definitely not opened exclusively. Anyone have any idea what could be causing this and what I could try do to get it working?

UPDATE:

I have tested the workstation installation on a computer with a fresh install of Windows XP SP3 and it is able to access the database file without a problem. So it seems that this error that I am getting is somehow specific to Windows 7. Is there maybe a known issue with Oledb drivers on Windows 7? My version of Windows 7, btw is 32 bit.

Comment: You mentioned that you are giving access to the share. Are you also giving permissions on the folder too? You will need the right to create files in the directory where the DB resides so it can write its locking file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, JohnJx. I have only given permissions to the share (group EVERYONE), is that not sufficient? Which user on the server must get given permissions?

Comment: Do you really only have one leading backslash instead of two in "\myserver\myshare\mydb.mdb"? That could be the problem right there.

Comment: No, actually there are 2 leading backslashes; when I wrote the question I typed 2 aswell, but stackoverflow is only showing 1. I think stackoverflow is seeing the one backslash as an escape character. I will correct that in my question, but I am definitely entering it correctly in the application.

Comment: Have you tried a fresh win7 install? Perhaps it's not related to xp, but to something else.

Comment: That is a good point, Moshe, I was thinking that too. The Windows 7 machine that I am testing on is my development machine so it has .Net 2008 and .Net 2010 installed. I think I will have to try it on a fresh install of Windows 7, but will have to do the install first before I can give more details on that.

Comment: Have you tried opening the database in Access rather than from your application?  The error message might be more detailed.  One possibility is that Access is refusing to open the file because the network share isn't a trusted location.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Yes, I did try that, I did a copy of the path that I am entering into the application and pasted it into the run box and Access opens the database without a problem. I really am thinking that I need to try this on another Windows 7 machine to determine if it is something specific to my Windows 7 installation.

Comment: Share permissions is not enough. You need permissions on both the share and folder.

Comment: Hmmm. I am not sure why this helped, but it did... I installed the 2007 Office System Driver found here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734. I got this link from the second post of the following thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/3d003721-6fb2-4927-9b29-bb6d7f35fa33. I am not sure whether this was just necessary for my installation of Windows 7 or if it would also be necessary with a fresh install on Windows 7, but I will do a test and find out.

Answer (score 0):

There could be so many things so it is hard to give a precise answer.
However, I had a similar problem a while a go and I wrote a post which I don't want to duplicate here:

http://walkinghumble.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/cannot-connect-to-an-access-mdb-file-located-on-the-network-through-oledb/

Maybe it will help if the underlying problem is the same (even though in my case it was an ASP.NET app). If not it will at least promote the process monitor if you did not know it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Jet 4.0 won't be able to open an Access file without the "Microsoft ADO Ext 2.8 for DDL and Security" COM reference set in the project's reference settings.  To check status of references go: Project-->References-->COM.

Other important references for making this work are:

"Microsoft ADO Data Control 6.0 (OLEDB)" COM reference

"Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library" COM reference

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Access reports this error when you have an undisposed MS Access process on your own machine. Check Task Manager's processes list (not applications).

Answer (score 0):

Try running these things down...

1. Are these computers on a domain? If so is the Win 7 box joined to the domain?
2. Did you set the permissions while being logged on at the server - or did you set the permissions from a share on another machine?  Set the permissions on the server itself.
3. From the Win 7 box - verify that you can open the share on the 2003 server, and change the access file name (just as a test - change it back of course).
4. Do you have Access installed on the win 7 box?  If so - see if you can access the share and use access to open the .mdb.